# How to remove multiple <none> docker images blocked by stopped containers quickly

Tags: docker, containers

I was trying to remove all dangling images including the images which have `<none>` as repo name or tag while listing with `docker images` command.

[image]

Now, if you try to remove the images , you may have seen that the `docker rmi <image_id>` commands might fail due to presence of invalid docker containers which were Exited abruptly and persisted as below.

[image]

It is tedious to remove all the containers and dependent images one by. Hence, is there a good way of removing such images quickly or in automated way ?

Comment: `docker system prune` will first remove stopped containers and then remove unused images.

Answer (score 1):

Easier way to remove such images and dependent containers to use following commands sequentially...

```
docker ps -a | grep "Exited " | awk '{print $1}' | xargs docker rm
docker images -f dangling=true | grep "none" | awk '{print $3}'| xargs docker rmi
```

you can also use `docker image prune` to remove all dangling images first.

Above commands will remove all dangling and `<none>` images from your system. You can also use `docker image prune -a` to remove **ALL UNUSED** images, but use it with **CAUTIONs**.